Increase and decrease length of 2 sides of a Triangle while keeping third side's length and opposite angle constant constant
I need to find a math formula that will help me with this kind of problem. I need to use it on my game's player controller which will act as a flying/hover line on surface. Basically, what i want is that the endpoints of a moving line to rotate towards surface it is moving without; it needs to keep its endpoints aligned to surface it is moving

You can also think about this problem as a triangle whose 2 sides lengths are changing while its third side and the opposite angle are constant. I was thinking about using law of sines/cosines but I am curios if there is a better way of doing this.


Any reaction to the answer from user @Oscar, Vasile?

The inscribed angle seems to be not so applicable for my use case, while i could potentially use circle geometry for my scenario, this would complicate the computation for the overall character controller. But it also opened my eyes to an old friend i forgot about: The Law of Cosines. It is what i need

If you can now answer your question, Vasile, let me encourage you to write up what you know and to post it as an answer, for posterity.

I ended up applying law of cosines.
If we treat the body of controller (the rotating line = AC = side b) and the ground as sides of a triangle, we can increase and decrease the sides associated with the ground (c and a) just by knowing the positions of each point of triangle and the angle of B.

Unity C# code:
/// <summary>
/// Function to calculate side B of a triangle based on other 2 sides and one Angle using the Law of Cosines
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sideA">Length of one of the dynamic sides of triangle. We want to pass here a different (higher/lower) value from the original length in order for AdjustSides to do something.</param>
/// <param name="sideC">Length of the constant side of triangle. This side length will remain the same after AdjustSides calculation.</param>
/// <param name="oppositeAngle">Value in degrees for opposite angle of constant side C</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static float CalculateSideB(float sideA, float sideC, float oppositeAngle)
{
    float radians = oppositeAngle * Mathf.Deg2Rad; // Convert degree to radians
    float cos = Mathf.Cos(radians);
    float sin = Mathf.Sin(radians);

    // Calculate b using the derived formula
    float sideB = sideA * cos + Mathf.Sqrt(sideC * sideC - sideA * sideA * sin * sin);
    return sideB;
}

public static void AdjustTrianglePoints(ref Vector3 A, Vector3 B, ref Vector3 C, float addedToBC)
{
    float lenAC = (A - C).magnitude; // Constant side length
    float lenBC = (B - C).magnitude; 
    float angle = Vector3.Angle(A - B, C - B); // Angle opposite to constant side
    lenBC += addedToBC;
    float lenAB = CalculateSideB(lenBC, lenAC, angle); 
  
    //Update points positions
    A = B + (A - B).normalized * lenAB; 
    C = B + (C - B).normalized * lenBC;

}



All the angles labeled A measure half the bottom arc between B and C indicated by the asterisk. Continue from there.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle#Theorem

This also lets you find the maximum possible lengths of the arbitrary sides by making it an isoceles triangle. Great!!!

The isosceles triangle msximizes the sum of the variable sides. One side or the other may be longer in a nonisosceles case than in the isosceles one.
